# SSH: agent key RSA SHA256:[hash] returned incorrect signature type

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, debian-buster

I just upgraded two machines from *Debian 9* to *Debian 10* and now, when I'm connecting to them using SSH, I'm getting the following warning:

```
agent key RSA SHA256:[hash] returned incorrect signature type
```

I have been using the exact same setup before and nobody was complaining.

Even though it doesn't have any impact on the ability to successfully connect, I would like to understand what it exactly means and how to fix it.

This is the `ssh -vvv` output:

```
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:[hash]
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512
agent key RSA SHA256:[hash] returned incorrect signature type
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using ssh-rsa
```

Do I understand it right that my SSH client is using a hashing algorithm to sign the key the SSH server doesn't like? Or is it SSH agent? How to configure it properly so the SSH server is not complaining, please?

I don't understand what's expected and what's actually used, confused by the `SHA256:` prefix vs. the message `signing using rsa-sha2-512`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I have been using the exact same setup before and nobody was complaining.

You upgraded from Debian 9 to Debian 10. That is no longer "the exact same setup".

> Do I understand it right that my SSH client is using a hashing algorithm to sign the key the SSH server doesn't like?

No; the SSH agent is using a hashing algorithm the *client* doesn't like.

Traditionally there was only one hash algorithm defined for each SSH key type, and `ssh-rsa` keys always used the SHA1 algorithm when making signatures. (Note that this is for signing data – authentication challenges – not keys themselves.)

Recently, as SHA1 is no longer state-of-the-art (or anywhere near), the combinations of RSA with SHA256 and SHA512 were specified and the ssh-agent protocol was extended with a flags field to request a different hash type than usual.

For this connection, your client and server have negotiated that a SHA512-based signature should be used instead. However, when the client asked ssh-agent to create the signature, ssh-agent ignored the new extension and just returned a SHA1-based signature instead. Usually this happens when the agent simply *does not support* the updated protocol.

The solution is to upgrade the SSH agent. Latest versions of OpenSSH and PuTTY both have agents compatible with the new protocol; GnuPG's gpg-agent should also support this as of v2.2.6.

> confused by the SHA256: prefix vs. the message signing using rsa-sha2-512.

The `SHA256:` prefix has *nothing whatsoever* to do with the signatures being made. It indicates the method that the key's fingerprint was generated (the fingerprint is a direct hash of the public key; not a signature). Old clients used to use MD5 for this purpose.

The fingerprint is shown for your information only (to indicate which key is being used) and its appearance doesn't affect the actual SSH connection.

Comment: Thank you, I'm starting to understand how it works. Where did you find the hash algorithm used by the agent? And who's message is `sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512` and how is it related?

Comment: All these messages come from your SSH client, because you've enabled the verbose logging options. I'm assuming that the agent generates SHA1-based signatures because that used to be the _only_ option for ssh-rsa keys, and it is much more likely for an agent to not support rsa-sha2-* at all (always using SHA1) than to support it incorrectly (using some other hash algo); that's what has caused practically all such messages in the past.

Comment: You're missing the point. I know from where those messages came since I provided that information. My concern was about the message `sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512` - is it just that negotiation between the client and the server and not the actual operation of the key signing or what does it actually mean, please?

Comment: That is the actual operation of the key signing. [Negotiation-related](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8308#section-3.1) messages are near "SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO" before user authentication even starts.

Comment: But the message says it's signing using SHA512 but my issue is that my key is **not** signed using SHA512, what am I missing here?

Comment: For one, SSH keys generally aren't "signed" in the first place – this whole thing has nothing to do with key signing at all. I'm not sure why you keep bringing it up.

Comment: Do you have a source for the information that gnupg 2.2.6 can handle this? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @SebastianWiesinger: This feature was requested in [Phabricator task T3880](https://dev.gnupg.org/T3880) and added in [Git commit 80b775bdbb85](https://github.com/gpg/gnupg/commit/80b775bdbb852aa4a80292c9357e5b1876110c00), which is present in Git tag `gnupg-2.2.6`.

Comment: @grawity Thank you very much! This information is almost nowhere to find.

Comment: FWIW this helped me.  I was using an older version of Pageant, in combination with an OpenSSH binary provided by Git For Windows.  I upgraded GFW to a new-enough version that it wouldn't accept SHA1, and it gave the `returned incorrect signature type` error. I had to upgrade to a recent-enough PuTTY/Pageant install, which resolved the signature-type issue.